# adding URL link to UIButton from JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uibutton

I am trying to link an button on the UI to a link that I receive after parsing a JSON response.  I've added an outlet to the button with the a variable containing the link.

```
@IBAction func goOnline(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(prodURL)
}
```

I parse the JSON data in a method called in viewDidLoad.

```
  if let convertedJSONIntoDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] {
       if let JSONurl = convertedJSONIntoDict["url"] as? String {
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
               self.prodURL = NSURL(string: JSONurl)!
          }
       }
 }
```

When I click on the button I don't get any response.  As always, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont have enough reputation to comment so i am adding here

what value do you get in json url???
even you dont need to save the value in the main queue you can also write like

```
self.prodURL = NSURL(string: JSONurl)!
```

Comment: I receive a string with a web link.  actually... i am double checking now.

Comment: sorry, you may be on to something.  I think the web link is missing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3

Define your strings and variables and then it's the following code:

```
    @IBAction func websiteButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let websiteURL = ("http://") + JSONurl!

    guard let url = URL(string: websiteURL) else {
        return //be safe
    }

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }

}
```

That should work.